# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 An error occured while executing doInBackground() IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm getting an error stating "FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1" and I'm not sure why. My logcat and source are included below. Please let me know if any additional information is required... I simply need to know how to avoid this situation.

Thanks in advance!

LOGCAT:

```
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.getValues(ConfigFinalActivity.java:366)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.InsertAPN(ConfigFinalActivity.java:334)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.updateTable(ConfigFinalActivity.java:689)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.access$0(ConfigFinalActivity.java:656)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity$TableUpdateRequestTask.doInBackground(ConfigFinalActivity.java:560)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity$TableUpdateRequestTask.doInBackground(ConfigFinalActivity.java:1)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-01 09:21:38.019: E/AndroidRuntime(8421):     ... 4 more
```

SOURCE SNIPPET:

(The error occurs here)

```
public ContentValues getValues() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }

        return values;

    }

    /*
     * Delete APN data where the indicated field has the values Entire table is
     * deleted if both field and value are null
     */
    private void DeleteAPNs(String field, String[] values)
            throws SecurityException {
        int c = 0;
        c = getContentResolver().delete(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null);
        if (c != 0) {
            String s = "APNs Deleted:\n";
            Log.d(TAG, s);

        }

    }

    /*
     * Return all column names stored in the string array
     */
    private String getAllColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        String s = "Column Names:\n";
        for (String t : columnNames) {
            s += t + ":\t";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button mXButton = null;
    // Progress
    private ImageView mProgressImageview1;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview2;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview3;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview4;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview5;
    private ImageView mLoadingCircle;

    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    int i, g = 0;
    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    public static BigInteger id1, id2;
    BigInteger[] id;
    public static Integer mdn1, mdn2;
    public static String car;
    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static String Base_URL = "https://www.settings.com/";
    NetworkTask task = new NetworkTask();
    NetworkTask tasks = new NetworkTask();
    InputStream stream = null;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        handler.setContext(this.getBaseContext());
        getImpVariablesForQuery();

        if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            try {
                // updating layout initially has updating text with 1 dot in the
                // xml
                setContentView(R.layout.updating);
                // This image view has the updating text to be progressively
                // updated
                // with dots addition
                ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
                // Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);
                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating1);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                ImageView loading2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
                // Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);
                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating2);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading2.getBackground();

                // mProgressImageview = (ImageView)
                // findViewById(R.id.updating_text);
                // mLoadingCircle = (ImageView)
                // findViewById(R.id.updating_hand);

                tasks.execute("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/317242424276/GetPhoneSettings-rsp-eng.xml");
                if (tasks.get() != null) {
                    stream = tasks.getInputStream();
                    Log.v("CfA", "here");

                } else if (tasks.get() == null) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.error);

                    // finish();
                    // finish();

                }

                handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

                Values = getContentValues();

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update APN table in separate thread
            new TableUpdateRequestTask().execute("");

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {

                task.execute("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2342324234/GetPhoneSettings-rsp-eng.xml");

                if (task.get() == null) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.error);

                } else if (task.get() != null) {
                    stream = task.getInputStream();
                    Log.v("CfA", "here");

                }
                /*
                 * DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                 * BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                 * InputStreamReader(in)); String strLine; while ((strLine =
                 * br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content on the console
                 * System.out.println (strLine); in.close(); }
                 */
                handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

                Values = getContentValues();
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        }
    }

    private ContentValues getContentValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        System.out.println("count" + count);
        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }

        return values;
    }

    private void getImpVariablesForQuery() {

        // to get MDN
        Integer MDN = Integer.parseInt(tm.getSimOperator());
        Log.d("MDN", MDN.toString());
        mdn1 = MDN % 1234;
        Log.d("mdn1", mdn1.toString());
        mdn2 = MDN / 1234;
        Log.d("mdn2", mdn2.toString());
        // to retrieve ICCID number of the SIM

        String ICCID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();

        Log.d("ICCID", ICCID);

        long d = 1234;
        BigInteger divisor = BigInteger.valueOf(d);
        BigInteger bInteger = new BigInteger(ICCID);

        id = bInteger.divideAndRemainder(divisor);
        id1 = id[1];
        System.out.println("ICCID%1234 = " + id1);
        id2 = id[0];
        System.out.println("ICCID/1234 = " + id2);
        // Check for the Carrier Type
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            car = "TMO";
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            car = "ATT";
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public ContentValues generateTFConfig() throws IOException, SAXException,
    ParserConfigurationException {
        // Extract the IMSI from the TelephonyManager instance
        // String imsi = tm.getSubscriberId();
        String operator = tm.getSimOperator();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Query the carrier table for the current data settings
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, "current=?",
                new String[] { "1" }, null);
        values = copyRecordFields(c);
        // Copy the Simple Mobile settings into values
        /*
         * query the server for the data settings put the returned data settings
         * into values
         */
        /*
         * String charset = "UTF-8"; String Append_URL = "settingsquery?";
         * String param1 = "mdn1="; String param2 = "&mdn2="; String param3 =
         * "&car="; String param4 = "&id1="; String param5 = "&id2="; String URL
         * = ""; String parameters = param1 + mdn1 + param2 + mdn2 + param3 +
         * car + param4 + id1 + param5 + id2; URL = Base_URL + Append_URL +
         * parameters; Log.i("url...", URL); new NetworkTask().execute(URL);
         */
        /*
         * if (handler.getQueryResult().equals("success")) { values.put("name",
         * handler.getName()); values.put("apn", handler.getApn());
         * values.put("mmsc", handler.getMMSC());
         * 
         * values.put("proxy", handler.getProxyAddress()); values.put("port",
         * handler.getProxyPort()); values.put("mmsproxy",
         * handler.getMMSCProxyAddress()); values.put("mmsport",
         * handler.getMMSCProxyPort()); values.put("mcc",
         * getString(R.string.mcc)); if
         * ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
         * values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
         * values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo))); } else if
         * ((tm.getSimOperator()) .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
         * values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
         * values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att))); }
         * 
         * } else if (handler.getQueryResult().equals("no match")) {
         * showAlert("no match"); } else if
         * (handler.getQueryResult().equals("no plan")) { showAlert("no plan");
         * }
         */
        return values;
    }

    /*
     * Insert a new APN entry into the system APN table Require an apn name, and
     * the apn address. More can be added. Return an id (_id) that is
     * automatically generated for the new apn entry.
     */
    public int InsertAPN() throws SecurityException {

        int id = -1;
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            // values2 = values1;
            values2 = getValues();
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values2);
                // System.out.println("values in insertAPN" + values1);
                if (newRow != null) {
                    c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Newly added APN:");
                    // TF Settings have been inserted
                    // Obtain the apn id
                    int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    id = c.getShort(idindex);

                    Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id
                            + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
        }
        return id;

    }

    public ContentValues getValues() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }

        return values;

    }

    /*
     * Delete APN data where the indicated field has the values Entire table is
     * deleted if both field and value are null
     */
    private void DeleteAPNs(String field, String[] values)
            throws SecurityException {
        int c = 0;
        c = getContentResolver().delete(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null);
        if (c != 0) {
            String s = "APNs Deleted:\n";
            Log.d(TAG, s);

        }

    }

    /*
     * Return all column names stored in the string array
     */
    private String getAllColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        String s = "Column Names:\n";
        for (String t : columnNames) {
            s += t + ":\t";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    /*
     * Copy all data associated with the 1st record Cursor c. Return a
     * ContentValues that contains all record data.
     */
    private ContentValues copyRecordFields(Cursor c) {
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        int row_cnt = c.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Total # of records: " + row_cnt);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();//
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
            Log.d(TAG, getAllColumnNames(columnNames));
            String row = "";
            for (String columnIndex : columnNames) {
                int i = c.getColumnIndex(columnIndex);
                row += c.getString(i) + ":\t";
                // if (i>0)//Avoid copying the id field
                // id to be auto-generated upon record insertion
                values.put(columnIndex, c.getString(i));
            }
            row += "\n";
            Log.d(TAG, row);
            Log.d(TAG, "End Of Records");
        }
        return values;
    }

    // showAlert displays the text contained in message as an alert
    public void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ConfigFinalActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showErrorAlert displays an alert with layout and a title
    private void showErrorAlert(int layoutRes, String title) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = ConfigFinalActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setTitle(title)
        .setView(inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.assisted_button),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
                try {
                    showNotification();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showNotification starts the process of sending notifications to the bar
    // to assist the user in updating the data settings on ICS and later
    // versions of Android
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    void showNotification() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        // handler.getQueryResponse();

        /*
         * String charset = "UTF-8"; String Append_URL = "settingsquery?";
         * String param1 = "mdn1="; String param2 = "&mdn2="; String param3 =
         * "&car="; String param4 = "&id1="; String param5 = "&id2="; String URL
         * = ""; String parameters = param1 + mdn1 + param2 + mdn2 + param3 +
         * car + param4 + id1 + param5 + id2; URL = Base_URL + Append_URL +
         * parameters; Log.i("url...", URL); new NetworkTask().execute(URL);
         */
        String field = getString(R.string.config_name_label);

        String value = Values.get("name").toString();
        int mId = 1;
        String title = "1 of " + UpdateActivity.TotalSteps + " (Update "
                + field + ":)";
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(value);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,
                NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(field, value);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mNotification != null) {
            outState.putString("NOTIFICATIONB", mNotification.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mXButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    // This thread performs the setting update and shows pseudo progress update
    private class TableUpdateRequestTask extends
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            int result = 0;

            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // The code below plays a Simple Promo animation
            // prior to displaying update success or failure message
            for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                // Invoke UI to change updating text to show 1 dot
                // And Increasing the level to reduce the amount of clipping and
                // slowly reveals the hand image
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
            }
            if (result != -1)
                return "success";
            else
                return "failure";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Show updated screen if table was successfully updated
            // Or alert indicating settings are not updated
            if (result.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else
                setContentView(R.layout.error);

        }

        // Framework UI thread method corresponding to publishProgress call in
        // worker thread
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Call function to update image view
            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2],
                    progress[3], progress[4]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show the relevant code . Obviously if `size` is `1` , index `1` is out of bounds !

Comment: you are getting that exception because your "i" is looking for the index 1, but the source you are trying to find is most likely on index "0".

Comment: How can this be avoided? (I'm taking over this code from another developer - I'm just not sure how to resolve the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is here: 
   `for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++)`  where you actually changes to index 1 and apparently the array size is 1 and therefor has only index 0 as valid position

It is really dangerous to use method variables to access arrays. They could change at any time in a threaded system as you do with `i`

EDIT: 
Use this instead. IF this is the only place that i is actually set and all the arrays are guaranteed to be of the same size.

```
for (i = 0; i < nameArr.size(); i++)
```

Comment: How can this be avoided? (I'm taking over this code from another developer - I'm just not sure how to resolve the issue)